# SQL INDEX for slow select

Tags: sql-server

Still learning SQL, I have the below select that works well, however, I would like to speed it up a bit. From what I understand about Indexing (Very little), I need to have a Unique ID column for an Index to have an effect?

None of my tables have a unique ID, even combinations of the columns would not result in a unique ID.

so my question is can Indexing help me? if so, how do I implement?
Or is there a better way of writing the below to execute faster?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,
        (SELECT SITE FROM SITES WHERE SITES.SITE_ID = tblJOIN.SITE_ID ) AS SITE, (SELECT ARTICLE FROM ARTICLES  WHERE ARTICLES.ARTICLE_ID = tblJOIN.ARTICLE_ID ) AS ARTICLE
    FROM tblJOIN) a
    INNER JOIN RANGE ON a.SITE=RANGE.SITE_ID AND a.ARTICLE=RANGE.ARTICLE_ID;
```

Comment: By standard, every table should have an `Id` column with `AUTO_INCREMENT`, and that will be the row's identifier. The only exception would be relationship tables (many to many), as far as I know.

Comment: *"I need to have a Unique ID column for an Index to have an effect?"* ; no, that isn't true. You do need a Unique Column to be able create a `CLUSTERED INDEX`, however, an `INDEX` does not require one; and they can still provide a performance increase. It is, however, an incredibly good (standard practice) to have a unique identifier of some kind on your table, so I would still highly recommend doing so; having a `CLUSTERED INDEX` could help you a lot more.

Comment: You have subqueries which are big red marks..try eliminating them

Comment: In addition to creating a (unique) Primary Key.
You will also want to make that   a Clustered Index based on that key.
This can be done through the SSMS or through commands.

Comment: Try sharing some test data,so that we could test "questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics) and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing aside, all of the sub-selects and the sub-query are pulling a lot of records into memory that you're just filtering off with your last outer join. This should return the same result set a little faster right away. The execution plan should give you more useful hints about where indexing might be helpful.

```
SELECT 
  J.*,
  R.*,
  S.[SITE] AS [SITE], 
  A.ARTICLE AS ARTICLE
FROM 
  [tblJOIN] AS J --The two original subselects joined here; good place to start.
JOIN --Rather than a subselect (row by row processing) added two joins...
  [SITES] AS S
    ON
      S.[SITE_ID] = J.[SITE_ID]
JOIN --...because joins are set based. Then SELECTed the needed fields from each.
  [ARTICLES] AS A
    ON
      A.[ARTICLE_ID] = J.[ARTICLE_ID]
 JOIN --Then just added your last join as written.
  [RANGE] AS R
    ON 
      S.[SITE] = R.[SITE_ID]
      AND 
      A.[ARTICLE] = R.[ARTICLE_ID];
```

Also, if you have anything to say about the table structures, it's not a best practice to have fields called SITE_ID and ARTICLE_ID in two tables that aren't the same data points. From the original query, tblJOIN.SITE_ID <> RANGE.SITE_ID and likewise with ARTICLE_ID. Also, it's not a best practice to have fields called Anything_ID that aren't, in fact, identifier columns.

Comment: Hello Eric, Thank you for the help. 7 mins down to 13 seconds. WOW. Your point about the naming of the columns is very helpful and makes sense to me. If I may ask, as I am still new to SQL, would you mind adding in a few comments into your query so that I can understand how and what it is doing? I am not sure what you mean by the execution plan. I will look into it.

Comment: Hi, @MarkBlackburn. I just dismantled your query and (guessing a fair bit) put it back together again for the quickest results. It helps to think of a query the way the SQL Engine does. Here's a starter piece: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/. So I started with "Where does the data come from?" Further comments added to the code. There's a mountain of information out there on execution plans. Read every word Brent Ozar writes. On anything.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to creating a (unique) Primary Key (using SSMS). You will also want to make a Clustered Index based on that key. This can be done through the `SSMS` Design Table or through commands.

Example  Code for creating (Clustered) Primary Key for your Table SItes using site_id as a primary key (you will have to make it unique):

```
USE [yourDBname]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [PK_SITES]    Script Date: 3/5/2018 9:19:11 AM ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SITES] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_SITE_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SITE_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

ADDENDUM:

> None of my tables have a unique ID, even combinations of the columns
>   would not result in a unique ID.

This does not suggest a well thought out design. It does appear that you have fields that are meant to function as unique IDs such as your SITES.SITE_ID. Granted not all tables must have a primary unique ID, but ones that represent an "Entity" should.

Answer (score 0):

Orignal

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT *
            , (SELECT SITE FROM SITES WHERE SITES.SITE_ID = tblJOIN.SITE_ID ) AS SITE
            , (SELECT ARTICLE FROM ARTICLES  WHERE ARTICLES.ARTICLE_ID = tblJOIN.ARTICLE_ID ) AS ARTICLE 
        FROM tblJOIN
     ) a
FROM RANGE r 
JION tblJOIN j
  ON a.SITE    = r.SITE_ID 
 AND a.ARTICLE = r.ARTICLE_ID;
```

Not sure I will come back and look at this